# If a functor $\varphi : C \to C'$ is full, then so is the functor $\varphi \circ$

Tags: category-theory

Let $I, C, C'$ be three categories, $\varphi : C \to C'$ a functor.  Then $\varphi$ determines a functor $\varphi \circ : \text{Fct}(I,C) \to \text{Fct}(I, C')$.  I want to show that if $\varphi : \text{Hom}_C(X,Y) \to \text{Hom}_C(\varphi X, \varphi Y)$ is surjective for all $X,Y \in C$, then $\varphi \circ : \text{Hom}_{\text{Fct}(I,C)}(F,G) \to \text{Hom}_{\text{Fct}(I,C')}(\varphi F, \varphi G)$ also surjective.  Hints please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $I$ be the category given by a single nontrivial arrow $f:I_0\to I_1$. Let $C$ be two disconnected copies of $I$, say $\iota_0,\iota_1:I\to C$ map to the separate copies of $I$. Let $C'=I$. Define $\varphi:C\to C'$ so that $\varphi\circ\iota_i=1_I$ ($i=0,1$).

Then, there is no natural transformation between $\iota_0$ and $\iota_1$ in $\mathrm{Fct}(I,C)$, whereas there is one between $\varphi\circ\iota_0$ and $\varphi\circ\iota_1$ in $\mathrm{Fct}(I,C')$.